# Aren't those Random Variables in a Stochastic Process the same "Functions"? Why do we need to index them?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

To my knowledge, a Stochastic Process is a set of Random Variables indexed by time.

Let's take the Bernoulli process as an example, which is a sequence of independent and identically distributed (iid) random variables.

But aren't those random variables in the Bernoulli process the same?
Since every random variable is just a function that maps an outcome from the sample space to a real number, $F: S \to \mathbb{R}$.

If they are just a set of random variables that measure a coin-flip $\{Head, Tail\}$ to $\{T, F\}$, what makes these random variables different so that I need to index them by time ($X_1, X_2, ...$)?

Comment: If two random variables are independent, they can't be the same variable. Otherwise there's no way to distinguish, say, $E[X_1^2]$ and $E[X_1 X_2]$.

Comment: @Semiclassical So can I say this is basically to distinguish them, even they have the same Domain and Range?

Comment: Intuitively, a random variable is the outcome of an experiment.  If we toss a fair coin $10$ times, we have $10$ i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v's, but obviously the outcome of the  tosses may be different.

Comment: @saulspatz "a random variable is the outcome of an experiment" I can understand this, but I am confused whenever I see their definition. Shouldn't I consider a random variable as a **function** by its definition "measurable function"? Since as far as I've known, a random variable is more like a function to me. It quantifies an outcome. I don't know how to treat it as a "value" :/

Comment: You may also find it worth examining the various types of equivalence for random variables detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Equivalence_of_random_variables) on the Wikipedia page. The r.v.s in a stochastic process are *equal in distribution*, but that's weaker than being equal (or even almost-equal). To put a finer point on it: If two random variables are truly equal, then the probability of them being equal is 1. But the probability of two independent coin flips being equal is 1/2.

Comment: Yes, technically a random variable is a measurable function on a probability space, but I was talking about the intuitive idea they attempt to capture.  There's some discussion of this [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/who-introduced-random-variables-into-probability)

Comment: @OODWaterball Try this: $X_{i}$ is the random variable that measure the $i$-th coin-flip $\left\{Head_{i},Tail_{i}\right\}$ to $\left\{T,F\right\}$, this explains how the independence works in your example and why these random variables are different.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. They help a lot and actually @Q9y5 your comment just killed my confusion, you really know where I was stuck! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe an example will help.  Let's take the sample space to be the unit interval $[0,1]$, and the probability measure $P$ thereon to be Lebesgue measure. If $\omega\in[0,1]$ let
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\omega_n\over 2^2}
$$
be the base 2 expansion of $\omega$. Now define $X_n(\omega) :=\omega_n$ to be the $n$th binary digit of $\omega$. [In the ambiguous case of an $\omega$ with a terminating expansion, I choose the one than terminates in all $0$s.] The functions $X_n:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ are all different functions,
but they all have the same *distribution*:
$$
P[X_n=0] = P[X_n=1] = {1\over 2},\qquad n=1,2,\ldots.
$$
In addition, the $X_n$s are mutually independent, so they constitute an instance of a "Bernoulli process".